# vis.js network: nodes z-index

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

Is there an equivalent of the CSS z-index for vis.js nodes?

Suppose that I have 2 kinds of nodes (in a graph with physics disabled): Circles and rectangles. I would like the rectangles to always be displayed over the circles when they are overlapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of a late reply but the short answer is: no

See this issue: https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/3146

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the [mentioned issue](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/3146), a more precise answer would be: there's no documented way to set z-index (and there's no such concept), but what you can use  (with a risk of getting this broken at some update) is nodes are drawn in the same order they are defined. From [comment](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/3146#issuecomment-307083020):

> I used the following test nodes:
>
> ```
> var nodes = [
>     {id: 'a', label: 'a', shape: 'dot'},
>     {id: 'b', label: 'b', shape: 'dot'},
>     {id: 'c', label: 'c', shape: 'dot'},
>     {id: 'd', label: 'd', shape: 'dot'}
> ];
> ```
>
> When not selected, these will draw in the node order:
>
> [image]
>
> Now, let's change the order:
>
> ```
> var nodes = [
>     {id: 'c', label: 'c', shape: 'dot'},
>     {id: 'b', label: 'b', shape: 'dot'},
>     {id: 'd', label: 'd', shape: 'dot'},
>     {id: 'a', label: 'a', shape: 'dot'}
> ];
> ```
>
> [image]